# 1 chicken lay how many eggs in 1 day

Tags: word-problem

Here's the question:

> A chicken and-a-half lays an egg and-a-half in a day and-a-half. 
>   Assuming eggs are fungible and fully divisible, how many eggs does one
>   chicken lay in a day?

Here's what I've done so far:

1.5 chicken 1.5 eggs in 1.5 days.  Multiplying that by 2 chickens gives:
3 chickens 3 eggs in 1.5 days.  Dividing that by 3 to get for 1 chicken gives:
1 chicken 1 eggs in 1.5 days

I'm not sure how to get for 1 day though.

Comment: If one chicken lays one egg in tow days, how many eggs per day does a chicken lay?  Generalize.

Comment: Can you explain how you got 1 chicken lays 1 egg in 2 days? I got 1 chicken lays 1 egg in 1.5 days.

Comment: Neither chickens nor eggs are "liquid" despite the assumptions of the question.  Anyway $\frac {1 \text{egg}}{1.5 \text {day}} = \frac {2}{3}$ egg per day.  Although I would prefer to say something along the lines of 2 eggs  every 3 days, or one egg with probability $\frac {2}{3}$

Comment: And you're right!  I was trying to suggest to you how to answer your question.  I'll bet that if it *had* come out to two days, instead of one-and-one-half, you'd be able to figure out the daily rate.  The same method will work if the daily rate is one and one-half.

Answer (score 1):

"A chicken and-a-half lays an egg and-a-half in a day and-a-half"

$\iff$

"A chicken and-a-half lays an egg in a day"

$\iff$

"A chicken lays $\frac{2}{3}$ of an egg in a day"

The key is to approach the problem logically and clean up the variables one at a time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how you can clean up the variables? Meaning how do you take out the halves in the chicken, egg, and day?

Comment: I consider logically two variables at a time. E.g If any number of chickens lay $n$ eggs in $n$ days, then I know that same number of chickens lay $1$ egg in $1$ day. Then consider another pair of variables and repeat until it is in the form you want.

Answer (score 0):

> A chicken and-a-half lays an egg and-a-half in a day and-a-half.

So we have
$$
1.5 \,\text{chicken} \times 1.5 \,\text{d} \times r = 1.5 \,\text{egg}
$$
where $r$ is the production rate:
$$
r 
= 
\frac{1.5}{1.5 \times 1.5} 
\frac{\text{egg}}{\text{chicken}\times\text{d}}
= 
\frac{2}{3} 
\frac{\text{egg}}{\text{chicken}\times\text{d}}
$$

> Assuming eggs are fungible and fully divisible, how many eggs does one chicken lay in a day?

After looking up fungible (= all eggs are the same value, there are no golden eggs in between :) we see
$$
1 \,\text{chicken} \times 1 \,\text{d} \times  
\frac{2}{3} 
\frac{\text{egg}}{\text{chicken}\times\text{d}}
= \frac{2}{3} \,\text{egg}
$$